# Can not debug in VSCode but can run the program fine through terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a total of three files:

`atom_list.c` - Where my functions are all created and stored

`atom_list.h` - Header file where all my functions are named and initialized

`main.c` - Where my functions are called.

In my main.c and atom_list.c files, I have #include "atom_list.h" and I use "gcc -Wall -g main.c atom_list.c -o lab1" to compile it. It compiles perfectly fine. However when I try to use VSCode to debug it by pressing F5 on my keyboard, it tells me that every time my atom_list.c functions are called within my main.c driver file, they are all undefined. Additionally, I can run the program through my terminal fine as well but when using the terminal, I have to add in an extra command line argument so the argument to run it would be ./main.exe 34 instead of just ./main.exe. Could that be the reason why? If it is, how would I resolve it?

Comment: What happens if you do not provide the additional random argument? For the debugging problem, make sure you include debugging symbols in the executable (in GCC, for example, you would use the `-g` option)

Comment: @LuxGiammi if I don't use the argument in the command line, I just get a response: Usage: ./lab1 list_size

Which comes from this section of code:

`if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./lab1 list_size\n");
        exit(1);
}`

Comment: You need to set up the arguments to the program before starting debugging it and, most importantly, compile it with the "debug support" (including debugging symbols in the executable), otherwise you'll be only able to step through the generated machine code (translated in assembly). This last step depends on the compiler you're using